# Airflow pass parameter to dag to use OUTSIDE of a task

Tags: airflow

```
import datetime as dt
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.models import Variable

@dag(start_date=dt.datetime(2022, 1, 1))
def my_dummy_dag():
    d0 = DummyOperator(task_id="d0")
    for i in range(1, 1+int(Variable.get("number", "3"))):
        d0 >> DummyOperator(task_id="d" + str(i))

my_dummy_dag = my_dummy_dag()
```

So I want to be able to send something to the DAG where I can control the number of DAGs that the loop makes.  The "Variable" is an "ok" solution, but I want to so something where I do not have to edit a Variable or the code.

Is there a way I can send a parameter to the DAG, maybe via a configuration when I trigger the DAG OR with a TriggerDagRunOperator() or something like that?

Comment: I am using airflow 2.2, so I CANNOT use the dynamic expand()

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Params. This is precisely what they are for.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.5/concepts/params.html

Comment: The question is for OUTSIDE of a task